# can not use jstl in jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I need to use jstl in my .jsp file.
I've done these prerequisite steps and I've gone no result:
1- I think the suitable version for me is `jstl-1.2.jar`. I downloaded and put it in common and suggested directory `\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` and use `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` in jsp file.
result : I saw this error in source code
`Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`
2- I added jar file to project build path.
result : Error of step 1 solved, but after running I saw this error: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` .
3- I put jar file in `\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF` and `\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\lib`.
result : any change.
4- I downloaded `jstl-api-1.2.jar` and `jstl-impl-1.2.jar` too, and I did like step 1 to 3 for them.
result: any change.
5- I set classpath in environment variable too.
result: any change.
6- I've done and undone any combination of above steps.
result: any change.
I use these utilities:

```
Windows 7, eclipse IDE, Apache Tomcat/7.0.77, Servlet Version: 3.0, JSP Version: 2.2
```

I've googled and also studied related stackoverflow posts and answers, but I've gotten no result. I am beginner of jsp. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Jar files from below link :

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi

Now add these JARs in your project, hope this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution**

1>right-click on your project and select 'Properties' -> 'Targeted Runtimes' and select the server you going to run your web app on (Tomcat 6 or 7).

2> add this in ur jsp file
`<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>` 
 **instead of** 
 `<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>`

For more info , look at [SO JSTL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)